# How can I run ethkey under Parity?

Tags: parity

How can I run [ethkey](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/tree/master/ethkey) under [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity)?

I cloned the Parity repo, built everything, and Parity is running, but I can't figure out how to run ethkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile it from source, use:

```
cargo build --release -p ethkey --features=ethkey-cli
```

in the root Parity directory and for usage instructions:

```
./target/release/ethkey --help
```

[Full documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/tree/master/ethkey) for the Ethereum key generator and signer.

Looking for key management? Use `ethstore`:

```
cargo build --release -p ethstore --features=ethstore-cli
```