# How to run ethkey under Parity

Tags: parity, rust

I want to run `ethkey` under Parity with [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16546/how-can-i-run-ethkey-under-parity).

But when I run the first command `cargo build --release -p ethkey --features=ethkey-cli` under the parity source folder, it returns:

> error: Package ethkey v0.2.0
>   (file:///home/yangyifei/Parity/parity/ethkey) does not have these
>   features: ethkey-cli

If I delete `--features=ethkey-cli`, it runs correctly. But I can't execute the second command, with returns no file or directory.

How can I run the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked it on the gitter. Thanks for @maciejhirsz's answer.

He told me to try this command

```
cargo build -p ethkey-cli --release
```

I try it under the parity source folder again.

It comply successfully. And I try to run the ethkey --help with this command:

```
./target/release/ethkey --help
```

And it works successfully!

Return like these:

```
Ethereum keys generator.   Copyright 2016, 2017 Parity Technologies (UK) Ltd

Usage:
    ethkey info <secret> [options]
    ethkey generate random [options]
    ethkey generate prefix <prefix> <iterations> [options]
    ethkey generate brain <seed> [options]
    ethkey sign <secret> <message>
    ethkey verify public <public> <signature> <message>
    ethkey verify address <address> <signature> <message>
    ethkey [-h | --help]

Options:
    -h, --help         Display this message and exit.
    -s, --secret       Display only the secret.
    -p, --public       Display only the public.
    -a, --address      Display only the address.

Commands:
    info               Display public and address of the secret.
    generate           Generates new ethereum key.
    random             Random generation.
    prefix             Random generation, but address must start with a prefix
    brain              Generate new key from string seed.
    sign               Sign message using secret.
    verify             Verify signer of the signature.
```

THANKS for @maciejhirsz and @5chdn♦'s help again. :)